# The image cannot be opened in python 3.6

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I got question about the remote sensing image cannot be opened in Spyder(python 3.6), however, the weird thing is there are two "tif" files (`Image.tif` and `Trend.tif`) in the same directory and the `Trend.tif` which is the classification result of the `Image.tif` can be open with the code like this:

```
img= Image.open('C:/zijianwang/Final/2/Trend.tif')
```

but when I change the name to:

```
img1= Image.open('C:/zijianwang/Final/2/Image.tif')
```

I got the error:

```
OSError: cannot identify image file 'C:/zijianwang/Final/2/Image.tif'
```

Can somebody know what's going on here? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

My current PIL version is 4.2.1 and it is working for me. My code is as follows:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("{image-folder-path}/Trend.tif")
```

Comment: The "Trend.tif" can be opened as same as you, but not "Image.tif". anyway, thanks a lot your comment.

Comment: Hi ZIJIAN, I did it with Image.tif as well and it works, have you solved the issue?

Comment: Hi Rick, actually not yet, I checked from other comments about this question someone said there is no way to open multi-bands image in Python, I can open the image with three bands(RGB), but the image I want to open cover six bands and cannot be opened.